# Inserting big string as a message to an alert dialog and showing it to the user

Tags: android, string, android-alertdialog

I want to show to the user an alert dialog when a specific text is pressed.
Until now i have accomplished to do it by setting an onClick function called showTerms() to that text.

```
  public void showTerms(View view){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("MyTitle");
    builder.setMessage(message); // < --
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    TextView messageView= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // Center the text

  }
```

It works just fine but if **message** variable is too long i get an error. I have read somewhere that a String can not exceed 65535 bytes.

The error i get :

> .." is too long for the constant pool

My questions :

> 1. Should i use AlertDialog? If yes, how could i exceed the 65535 bytes limit?
> 2. Is there a better way or a custom library for that purpose?(showing Terms & Conditions to the user)

Comment: Use CustomDialog with ScrollBar

Comment: @SathishKumarJ if my variable "message" which is a String is too big it can not even compile the project, how can i exceed the limit of string?